# Scheduling an Interview

Tags: interviewing

Whenever I get a phone call from an employer or hiring manager for an interview I often let them decide or propose a date since most of the time they don't ask me when I'm available to meet. They usually already have a day in mind and ask me if I would be available that day/time. What kind of impression would I be making if I tell them that I'm available the next day?

Comment: Are you actually unavailable at the specified time?  Are you asking because you want to feign being busier than you really are?

Answer (score 2):

The process of finding a mutually acceptable time to meet is a process of negotiation and adjustment, which goes both ways. Your preference for the next day is perfectly legitimate. It doesn't mean you'll get your way but if you don't put out the idea, you won't get a response to the idea.

Comment: Yeah, the interview is going to have to occur at a time which works for both the employer and the candidate. I really don't think it makes any difference "who speaks first" in a negotiation like this. It's not like who mentions a number first in a salary negotiation! :-)